# Communication LoRa

Tags: module, communication, lora

I have two LoRa modules, the transmitter is an E32-900T20D (with ESP32 DevKitC V4) and the receiver is a LoRa32U4. The problem is that the receiver is not receiving anything from the transmitter. Here is the code for the transmitter:

```c
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "LoRa_E32.h"

LoRa_E32 e32ttl100(&Serial2,UART_BPS_RATE_9600 ); 

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(500);
  // Startup all pins and UART
  e32ttl100.begin();
  Serial.println("Hi, I'm going to send messages every second!");
  // Send first message
  ResponseStatus rs = e32ttl100.sendMessage("Hello, world?");
  // Check if message was sent successfully
  if (rs.code == 1) {
    Serial.println("Message sent successfully");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Failed to send message");
  }
}

void loop() {
  delay(2000); 
  // Send message
  ResponseStatus rs = e32ttl100.sendMessage("Hello, world?");
  // Check if message was sent successfully
  if (rs.code == 1) {
    Serial.println("Message sent successfully");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Failed to send message");
  }
}
```

Here is the result of the transmitter:

> Hi, I'm going to send messages every second!
> Message sent successfully
> Message sent successfully
> Message sent successfully

Here is the code for the receiver:

```c
#include <SPI.h>
#include <LoRa.h>

#define ss 8
#define reset 4
#define dio0 7

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  LoRa.setPins(ss, reset, dio0);
  if (!LoRa.begin(868E6)) {
    Serial.println("Starting LoRa failed!");
    while (1);
  }
  // Set signal bandwidth to 125kHz
  LoRa.setSignalBandwidth(125E3);
  // Set TX power to 20dBm
  LoRa.setTxPower(20);
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
}

void loop() {
  int packetSize = LoRa.parsePacket();
  if (packetSize) {
    // received a packet
    Serial.print("Received packet with RSSI ");
    Serial.print(LoRa.packetRssi());
    Serial.print(": ");
    while (LoRa.available()) {
      Serial.write(LoRa.read());
    }
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, !digitalRead(LED_BUILTIN));
  }
}
```

Knowing that both are configured for 868 Mhz, what is the problem? Any help please?

Answer (score 2):

Ebyte modules that are UART-managed are not really LoRa devices. Their settings do not match that of regular LoRa modules. I have long suspected that they use FSK transmission instead of LoRa. Stay entirely within the Ebyte ecosystem, or out. Do not mix non-Ebyte and Ebyte modules, because if you do, all you will ensure is misery.